# function Prototype in jQuery

Tags: jquery, prototypejs

I have two files - *prototype.js* and *jquery.js*

In *prototype.js* have:

```
function check(www) {
//....
}
```

in *jquery.js* have:

```
jQuery('#aaa').click(function() {
    var bbb = $this.val();  
        //-----
         check(www);
        //--------

    });
```

How can I correctly use check?

Answer (score 2):

If it were really declared as shown, you could just call it as you've shown. It doesn't matter that it's defined in one file and then used in another; once the files are loaded, they all exist in the same execution environment. But I don't recall Prototype having a `check` function at global scope.

Note that if you're using Prototype and jQuery on the same page, you have to tell jQuery to not use the `$` symbol:

```
jQuery.noConflict();
```

Then you can just intersperse use of Prototype and jQuery all you want. Example:

```
<script src='prototype.js'></script>
<script src='jquery.js'></script>
<script>
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(function() {
    // Get a jQuery instance containing elements with class "foo"
    var foo = jQuery(".foo");

    // Retrieve the first matching element, use Prototype's `$()` to extend it
    // (automatic on some browsers, not on IE), then call Prototype's `update` function.
    $(foo[0]).update("Hi there");
});
</script>
```

As you can see, you can intersperse the two if you like. I'm not saying it's a good idea, but sometimes it's necessary, particularly when you're incrementally transitioning a page or site from one library to another.

If you're used to writing jQuery code with the `$` symbol, you can still do that for entire sections of the code if you like. Here's a fairly common idiom:

```
(function($) {
    // Within this function, $ = jQuery
    ....
})(jQuery);
```

That shadows the `$` symbol within that function (by making it an argument), and passes `jQuery` in for that argument. Or you can be more explicit:

```
(function() {
    var $ = jQuery; // Within this function, $ = jQuery
    ....
})();
```

That does much the same thing, but more obviously.

Comment: I understand it, but i can't use function prototype in jQuery

Comment: @asifg: You'll have to give a more complete explanation of what you're trying to do and what isn't working.

Comment: This is in the first post. What i need add to check(www) from prototype in jQuery('#aaa').click(function() {

Comment: Here was the response with namespace, but someone deleted

Comment: @asifg: Again, as I said above, if the function were really defined as you've shown, you could just call it the way you've shown. It doesn't matter if it's in a different file. Show a *more complete example*, say what doesn't work, and people will be happy to help you.